# What's the `tcp.analysis` ? and `tcp.analysis.flags`?

Tags: wireshark

[image]

I have several questions about wireshark packet.

why when I request a website, there will get two TCP connection? you see the first two packets60907 -> 80 and 60908->80

2.what's the `tcp.analysis` ? and `tcp.analysis.flags`?

3.is it possible to sort the TCP connection packets by each connect?

I mean, if there have two TCP connections, you see the 1-6 packet.
is it possible to list like: `1 3 5 2 4 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably @244boy already has the answer, but for anyone else wondering the same thing, Jaap Keuter, one of the Wireshark core developers, provided the following answer at the Wireshark Q&A site [here](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/18571/whats-the-tcpanalysis-and-tcpanalysisflags/).

---

1. The web client tries to optimise the user experience by trying to get all information as fast as possible. It then helps to open multiple TCP connections to get at the various resources that make up a web page, e.g., the text content and graphics.
2. `tcp.analysis` is the Wireshark analysis of the TCP sequence numbers and acknowledgements so far. It includes metrics like RTT, bytes in flight, bytes since last PSH. The `flags` are noticeable aspects of the current packet.
3. Yes, add a column (type custom) with field `tcp.stream` as field, and use that to sort.

---

**Note**: I've only provided Jaap's answer here locally in the unlikely event that the Wireshark Q&A site isn't accessible.